# Interface to concrete class conditional instantiation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, pojo

I have a Spring based Java application where a lot of classes use the following autowired interface.. they work off this interface at all places.

```
@Autowired
private IOperatingSystemManager m_operatingSystemManager;
```

Right now, there is only one implementation of the interface as follows:

```
@Component
public class WindowsManager implements IOperatingSystemManager 
{
 // Windows based shenanigans
}
```

And the application works as expected. Spring is happy. Everybody is happy.
Alright, not everybody...

So, I want to add another concrete implementation of `IOperatingSystemManager` ..

```
@Component
public class LinuxManager implements IOperatingSystemManager 
{
 // Linux based shenanigans
}
```

What we want is the auto wiring of IOperatingSystemManager conditionally based on a properties file setting. (say.. os=windows.. basically something that is an arbitrary string and cannot be derived from system properties etc. simply because this is a dummy example. the actual managers are not OS related.)

I don't want to change any of the classes who have autowired to the interface and are working off the interface. All I need is for Spring to look at some logic that will dictate the Autowiring of the variables and wire up the right concrete instance for:

```
@Autowired
IOperatingSystemManager m_operatingSystemManager
```

at all the gazillion places.

The documentation & web search talk about profiles, condition, bean factory, qualifiers etc.. but we don't want to use Profiles; and Qualifiers seem to be needing changes to all the interface variable annotations.

Factory methods look promising, but being new to Spring, couldn't find a crisp answer.

What is a simple and recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: You should take a look at spring profiles

Comment: Why do you not want to use profiles? They would be the obvious solution... Using some home brew instead is most likely a bad idea. That would be more error prone and harder to understand when maintaining the code.

Comment: @TobiasKremer thanks for your comment. we already have pre-defined profiles which are used to control connection strings etc. and we don't want to introduce new profiles for this purpose. at least not as first preference. and i agree that we don't want a home brew solution. if no other simpler natural solution works out, then we'll give profiles a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of scanning the `WindowsManager` class, create one concrete instance that implements the `IOperatingSystemManager` interface or another one, depending on the your logical conditions.

First, remove the `@Component` annotation from the `WindowsManager` class.

Then, create and scan this `@Configuration` class, which will act as a factory for your beans:

```
@Configuration
public class OperatingSystemManagerFactory {

    @Bean
    public IOperatingSystemManager getOperatingSystemManager() {
        if ( /* some logic that evaluates to true if windows */ ) {
            return new WindowsManager();
        } else {
            // Linux default option ;)
            return new LinuxManager();
        }
    }
}
```

With this solution, you shouldn't need to update anyone of your classes that reference the `IOperatingSystemManager` interface.

Comment: Federico, do i need to do anything else to bootstrap this configuration class so that spring knows about this? (xml or annotate it with component etc.)

Comment: @rajanadar No, it's enough with `@Configuration`, which a Spring annotation such as `@Component`. You nnes to scan it.

Comment: when i run all tests, the factory code was invoked and some tests pass. but a lot of them fail, as spring seems to be looking into one of the concrete classes (OperatingSystemManager.class) to get a reference to IOperatingSystemManager autowired as constructor parameters in a lot of classes. not sure why Spring doesn't look at the factory method for this bean and is looking at the concrete class which has no autowire or component annotaions?

Comment: this is the exact exception.. Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [com.company.IOSManager]: : Error creating bean with name 'OSManager' defined in file [D:\dev\Build\com.company\build\com\company\OSManager.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.company.OSManager]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.company.OSManager.<init>();

my concrete classes are named OSManager and LinuxOSManager

Comment: @rajanadar So your bean does not have a no args constructor. Add it to the class if it makes sense. If it doesn't, add the arguments to the factory methods and pass them to the constructor of your bean.

Comment: thanks Federico. the issue was that our unit tests has a component-scan context filter setup for OSManager and I hadn't changed the expression to this new bean factory class. Changing it, fixed all the issues. thanks a lot for your help Federico.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know which version of spring you are using but you have options for this

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-conditional-bean-configuration/

Here, as you can see, you can create a bean based on a condition that you can decide. It actully gave your example, Windows and Linux :), so i believe thats what you are looking for.

Edit:

If you are using spring-boot, you have some other Conditional annotations

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-condition-annotations

Comment: thanks Gokhan. i used the Configuration option expanded out by Federico below.